# Is Firestore Security Rule .hasAny(['A', 'B', 'C']) still available for use?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Can't seemed to use Firestore Security Rule .hasAny(). Is this method deprecated or no longer available?

[image]

I am using it like

```
/// Functions - NOT WORKING!!! ///
function isTeamMember(teamId, userId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId].hasAny(['OWNER', 'ADMIN', 'STANDARD'])
}
```

The Firestore data is structured as such

```
- team_access_privilege (COLLECTION)
-- teamId (DOCUMENT)
--- userId1 (KEY) : 'OWNER' (VALUE)
--- userId2 (KEY) : 'ADMIN' (VALUE)
--- userId3 (KEY) : 'ADMIN' (VALUE)
--- userId4 (KEY) : 'STANDARD' (VALUE)
```

There are 4 users in this team.

I also tested that the below functions and they work well.

```
/// Functions - Working Well ///
    function isOwnerOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'OWNER'
    }
```

My goal is to check that as long as userId exists in team_access_privilege he/she can access the data. I tried using **exists()** but the simulator takes forever to run. I am giving up on using **exists()**. I am not sure if it is a known issue.

Below this takes forever to run

```
/// Functions - Not working too ///
    function isTeamMember(teamId, userId) {
      return exists(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId])
    }
```

**All in all, my goal is to check that the user is a 'OWNER', 'ADMIN', or 'STANDARD' of the team to read / write data.**

---

Edit 1

Tried @Doug Stevenson's answer, and it does NOT work

```
['OWNER', 'ADMIN', 'STANDARD'].hasAny([get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId]])
```

This is the error message.
[image]

I tried another approach, and it worked.

```
/// Functions - Working Well ///
    function isOwnerOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'OWNER'
    }

/// Functions - Working Well ///
    function isAdminOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'ADMIN'
    }

/// Functions - Working Well ///
    function isStandardOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'STANDARD'
    }

/// Functions - Then This WOrks ///
    function isTeamMember(teamId, userId) {
      return isOwnerOfTeam(teamId, userId) || isAdminOfTeam(teamId, userId) || isStandardOfTeam(teamId, userId)
    }
```

['', '', ''].hasAny( get() ) does not work. So is get().hasAny(['', '', '']). Exists does not work as well for my said data structure.

This is just puzzling. Anyway I have a working security rule for now. Hope @Doug Stevenson could help figure out **a more efficient way to check that the user is a 'OWNER', 'ADMIN', or 'STANDARD' of the team to read / write data.**

Answer (score 8):

`hasAny` is a method on array types, [as documented here in the rules reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny).  You use it to determine if a list type field contains any of the values in the given list.  It seems that you're trying to use it on a string.

Perhaps you can use it in the opposite direction to figure out if the string role of the user id is one of the three other roles given:

```
['OWNER', 'ADMIN', 'STANDARD'].hasAny([get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId]])
```

Comment: How about using exists( get() ) ? or simply using exists() is this possible?

Comment: By the way the above method you recommended does not work. Another error. Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [65], column [45]. Unsupported operation error. Received: list.hasAny(string). Expected: list.hasAny(list).

Comment: You have to put the get() in square brackets to make it a list. It compiles, but I discovered it doesn't work the way I expect.

Comment: I updated the question with Edit 1. It's working with a workaround. But can't get .hasAny() or exists() working with my said data structure.

Comment: a related question to this. Perhaps you might know the answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/51074728/3073280