# How to count/calculate Firestore Security Rule access limit for get() nested get()?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is [a limit of 10 get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits) for single-document requests and query requests. How many access call would the below snippet be for access role of 'STANDARD'?

```
function isOwnerOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'OWNER'
}

function isAdminOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'ADMIN'
}

function isStandardOfTeam(teamId, userId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team_access_privilege/$(teamId)).data[userId] == 'STANDARD'
}

function isTeamMember(teamId, userId) {
  return isOwnerOfTeam(teamId, userId) || isAdminOfTeam(teamId, userId) || isStandardOfTeam(teamId, userId)
}
```

---

And what if I have a get() nested get() with OR operators. How many access call would that be?

For instance

```
function getTeamId(teamName) {
  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team/$(teamName)).data[id]
}

match /teamSecretStory/{teamName} {
      allow read: if isTeamMember(getTeamId(teamName), request.auth.uid);
}
```

All in all, how many access is this get() nested get() with OR operators for role 'STANDARD'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules, like all major programming languages, short circuit their logical ORs, left to right.  Each OR is evaluated from left to right until one of them evaluates true, or all of them evaluate true.  Same for logical AND, except the first false evaluation will stop the entire circuit.

Comment: Correction: Each OR is evaluated from left to right until one of them evaluates true...

Comment: I need your help to count it in terms of best case and worst case. For isTeamMember() the best case is 1 get() access call. The worst case is 3 get() access calls. How about the situation for get() nested get()?

Comment: what is the best case and worst case in the number of access calls for isTeamMember(getTeamId(teamName), request.auth.uid) ?

Comment: I think you can figure out what you need based on the description I gave.  If you have followup questions, please ask them as a different question on SO.  You have no "nested" calls to get(), only sequential calls.