# Making a client-side request to satisfy a Firestore permissions rule that uses ACLs as arrays with hasAny()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Consider the following :

A Firebase auth user has an ACL (access control list)

`user.roles = [ a, b, c ]`

Each record in a collection must be secured with a list of roles that are permitted to perform read/write operations on the document:

`resource.access.roles = [ c, d, e ]`

If there is an intersection between the two arrays, the operation should be permitted.

```
function userHasAccess (resource) {
  return getUser().roles.hasAny(resource.data.access.roles)
}

match /{collection}/{id} {
  allow read: if userHasAccess(resource)
}
```

Note: in the Firebase console, getUser().roles is an array and resource.data.access.roles is an array and there IS an intersection between them. Consequently, IN THE CONSOLE, the request is permitted.

Question: how to query this collection from the client whilst satisfying the rule.

What I had expected is that this would work.

```
ref
  .collection(collection)
  .where('access.roles', 'array-contains-any', user.roles)
```

... would satisfy the rule and allow the read operation, but it does not. It throws standard permissions error, even though I can read the `ref.collection(collection).doc(id)` just fine.

`FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Would appreciate an example or better a ref to the docs where it shows how to formulate a query in the client that satisfies the [hasAny()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) rule that the framework provides.

** EDIT: ** Added full details per Doug's recommendation:

The database is structured as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAuthUser(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    function isTenantUser(env, tenantId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/envs/$(env)/usersMap/$(request.auth.uid)).data.tenant == tenantId
    }

    function getUser(env, tenantId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/envs/$(env)/tenants/$(tenantId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data
    }

    function userHasAccess (env, tenantId, resource) {
      return resource.data.access.role in getUser(env, tenantId).roles
    }

    // note if set env here, have to pass through all fns to match path
    match /envs/{env} {
      match /usersMap/{userId} {
        allow read: if isAuthUser(userId)
      }

      match /tenants/{tenantId} {

                allow read: if isTenantUser(env, tenantId)
        allow update: if getUser(env, tenantId).account.isAdmin

        match /lists/{settingId} {
          allow read, update: if isTenantUser(env, tenantId)
        }

        match /settings/{settingId} {
          allow read: if true
          allow update: if getUser(env, tenantId).account.isAdmin
        }

        // todo: users can't change admin flag or email
        match /users/{userId} {
          allow read: if true
          allow create: if getUser(env, tenantId).account.isAdmin
          allow update: if getUser(env, tenantId).account.isAdmin || request.auth.uid == userId
        }

        // todo: permissions on read/update
        match /{collection}/{id} {
          allow read, update, delete: if userHasAccess(env, tenantId, resource)
          allow create: if true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on this, I want to secure access to the following url:

```
/databases/$(database)/documents/envs/$(env)/tenants/$(tenantId)/{collection}/{documentId}

eg:
/databases/$(database)/documents/envs/devleopment/tenants/shalom-shul-20AZ/cases/case-one
```

with ACLs where the user record is: [image: user record is here]

and the case record is: [image: case record is here]

Under these conditions, the rules evaluate as allowed in the firebase console, but the client-side query as posted returns denied error (even though i can read any individual doc just fine).

Comment: Please edit the question to show **all** of the relevant code and data.  getUser, the actual document data (a screenshot will help, or a more detailed view of its contents), the name of the collection you're querying, and the contents of the documents that should be returned.  Basically, we should be able to construct the entire situation and test it for ourselves using what you give here.  Hard code as much as you can - don't show variables.

Comment: Could you please check this other post from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073887/is-firestore-security-rule-hasanya-b-c-still-available-for-use) and check if it helps? I believe it indicates a way for you to check if specific roles are allow to access documents - seems a very similar case to yours.

Comment: @gso_gabriel - this post is about having trouble with the .hasAny() method because he's calling it on a string. My problem isn't using the method. This works fine in the console. It's how to send a query to the api that satisfies the requirements of the permissions rules written around .hasAny(). Presumably you would need an array for the resource and an array in the request - and the only way to do that is using .where(resourceArray, 'array-contains-any', [ some array ]) - but this doesn't pass permissions, even though the arrays DO have intersecting values. It's quite different.